# gnuplot and stdin data, different behavior between script and command line

Tags: gnuplot

Given this very symple dataset:

```
0 0.2
1 0.1
2 0.3
3 0.25
4 0.15
e
0 0.15
1 0.25
2 0.3
3 0.1
4 0.2
```

If I invoke gnuplot embedding the program using the -e switch:

```
cat h.dataset | gnuplot -p -e "plot '-' u 1:2 w l, '-' u 1:2 w l"
```

I see the exepcted result (two lines of different colors, sign that it extracted two dataset from stdin)

On the other hand if I put the plot command in a file and execute:

```
cat h.dataset | gnuplot -p h.gpi
```

I obtain this error:

```
"h.gpi", line 1: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
"h.gpi", line 1: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot '-' u 1:2 title 'a' w l, '-' u 1:2 title 'b' w l
                                                     ^
"h.gpi", line 1: x range is invalid
```

My gnuplot version is: `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5`

I also tried the variant: `plot '<cat' u 1:2 title 'a' w l, '' u 1:2 title 'b' w l`, but it does a different thing, because the first graph slurps all the data (and plot two lines with the same color == same dataset) and the second graph emits just a warning

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? From `help special-filenames`: "'-' is intended for situations where it is useful to have data and commands
 together". It looks like you are trying to split them across multiple files?

Comment: On SO you can found discordant answers about gnuplot and stdin; some answers report '<cat' as the correct way, while others says that '-' (originally intended for data put inline after the plot command) also works (maybe the behaviour has changed at some point?). What I want to do is to feed a gnuplot script with the output of a program that describes a fixed number of different graphs (>1)